# adjusting line height of a multi-line expression() statement with grid or lattice graphics

Tags: r, expression, lattice, r-grid, plotmath

I have a lattice figure that contains a multi-line `expression()` statement.  I want to fine–tune the vertical space between the lines of this statement.  Is there a way to do this?

Here is code that demonstrates the problem:

```
library(devtools)
library(grid)
library(lattice)
source_gist(2732693)  # source grid.expr()


# PANEL FUNCTIONS
myPanel1 <- function () {
  grid.text(
    label = expression(atop("This is", paste("italicized ", italic(F))),
    gp = gpar(lineheight = 5)))
}
myPanel2 <- function () {
  grid.expr(
    as.expression(
      list("This is", bquote(paste("italicized ", italic(F))))),
    gp = gpar(lineheight = 5))
}    


# DRAW THE FIGURES
xyplot(1 ~ 1, panel = myPanel1)
xyplot(1 ~ 1, panel = myPanel2)
```

This code offers two ways to create a multi-line `expression()` statement in a lattice plot.  But the `gp` argument is ignored in both cases, and I don't see a way to adjust the vertical spacing of lines within the expression.  Is there a way to do this, short of "manually" positioning the lines with a separate `grid.text` or `grid.expr` command for each line?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you could try with gtable

```
library(gtable)
library(grid)

grid.expr <- function(labels, ..., 
                      width=NULL, heights=NULL, 
                      margin=unit(0.5,"line")){

  gl <- lapply(labels, textGrob, ...)

  if(is.null(heights))
    heights <- do.call(unit.c, lapply(gl, grobHeight)) + margin

  widths <- do.call(max, lapply(gl, grobWidth))
  gt <- gtable_matrix("table", grobs = matrix(gl,ncol=1), 
                      widths=widths, heights=heights)
  grid.draw(gt)
}

grid.newpage()
grid.expr(LETTERS[1:5], heights=unit(1:5,"line"))
```

Comment: Thank you.  This solution works well, and it's especially nice in that it offers two distinct ways to vary the vertical distance between lines (the "heights" and "margin" arguments).

Comment: explanation would be helpful, this is difficult to decipher